# How to make counter stats spinner in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to Ionic and I want to make counter stats spinner in Ionic UI. I searched a lot but i am not able to make the counter stats.

Can anyone help me in this. Please.[image]

Please help me in this. I haven't done any code because I am not able to get what code should be written for this.

Comment: Can you share what you have done?

Comment: @AnandRaj . I am not able to get what code should be written for this. So, can you help me in this. Please. Can you provide me the code for this?

Comment: here you have to try and post some code otherwise there is a chance for CLOSING your question

Comment: @AnandRaj . Okay, I will try and paste the code here.